# ORA-00936: отсутствует выражение ORA-06512

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-developer

```
При вызове процедуры выходит ошибка



PROCEDURE GETWAGONSINVENTORYDATAOLAP(RESULT OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
    QUERY VARCHAR(4000);
  BEGIN
    QUERY := 'select ow.shortname OWNER, wt.shortname WAGONTYPE';
    FOR I IN (SELECT USEDWAGONTYPES.WAGONSTATUS
              FROM (SELECT DISTINCT W.WAGONSTATUS_ID WAGONSTATUS
                      FROM WAGON W) USEDWAGONTYPES
              ORDER BY WAGONSTATUS) LOOP
      QUERY := QUERY||', WagonPackage.GetStatusCount(ow.id, wt.id,'||I.WAGONSTATUS||') STATUS_'||I.WAGONSTATUS;
    END LOOP;
    QUERY := QUERY||' from owners ow, (select distinct w.wagontype_id from wagon w where w.In_Inventory_Park = 1) USED_WAGONTYPES, Wagontypes wt'
                  ||' where wt.id = USED_WAGONTYPES.WAGONTYPE_ID'
                  ||'   and WagonPackage.GetStatusCount(ow.id, wt.id) != 0'
                  ||' order by ow.orderindex';
    OPEN RESULT FOR QUERY;
  END;
```

Вот сама ошибка

```
function DbManagerCall.ExecuteNonQueryCursor: Username:Denis_Kurbangaliev Procedure: WagonPackage.GetWagonsInventoryDataOLAP 
     Error: ORA-00936: отсутствует выражение
    ORA-06512: на  "DBTC.WAGONPACKAGE", line 473
    ORA-06512: на  line 1
     
     StackTrace:    at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.CheckError(OciErrorHandle errorHandle, Int32 rc)
       at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.Execute(OciStatementHandle statementHandle, CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean needRowid, OciRowidDescriptor& rowidDescriptor, ArrayList& resultParameterOrdinals)
       at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.Execute(OciStatementHandle statementHandle, CommandBehavior behavior, ArrayList& resultParameterOrdinals)
       at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Common.DbDat`введите сюда код`aAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
       at RemoteLib.DbManagerCall.ExecuteNonQueryCursor(String procedure, Dictionary`2 values, Guid sessionCode) in D:\Work\Projects\TransCom\src\Wagons\RemoteLib\DbManagerCall.cs:line 312 
     Inner Messages:ORA-00936: отсутствует выражение
    ORA-06512: на  "DBTC.WAGONPACKAGE", line 473
    ORA-06512: на  line 1
```

Comment: Выведете в строку, которая у вас получается после сборки и попробуйте выполнить сформированный sql отдельно. Скорее всего есть ошибка в собранном sql выражении

Comment: Подскажите как это сделать)

Comment: в данном вопросе я новичок

Comment: Добавить строку в процедуру `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(QUERY);` Ну и выполнить выполнить саму процедуру. Далее в зависимости от того, где вы ее запускаете, должен появиться текст вашего собранного SQL